# How to disable HDMI port? (NVidia)

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

Can I disable the HDMI Port somewhere on my computer?

Reason: I always have to crouch under my table and plug the HDMI cable from my TV in, to watch a movie. But if I let it plugged in, I lose massive amounts of frames per seconds, if I play a game, even if the TV doesn't run (of course).

I want to disable the port manually, so when I want to watch a movie, I just have to "undisable" it to make a connection to my TV.
OS: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Windows + P at the same time to set your dual-screen preferences. Computer-Only will show on the PC screen, Projector-Only will only show on the TV, duplicate will show the same thing on both and Extend will let you use them as one big workspace.